# DSolve for first order nonlinear equation is solution numerical or analytical?

Tags: numerics, differential-equations, nonlinear

Hi I'm new to mathematica so I may have a somewhat trivial question. my code below solves and plots the results of a first order nonlinear ODE. The solutions mathematica gives me contains & and #1 which I don't know what those mean.

```
Clear[m, z, p, h, ld, to, td, mo, hc, mb, cb, t]
Clear[mm, sol, sol20, tt, mmm]

sol = DSolve[{m'[
 t] == -((m[t]^(2/3))/(p^(2/3)))*(h/ld (to - td + ((mo - m[t])*hc)/(mb*cb))), m[0] == mo}, m[t], t]
mm[t_] := Part[sol, 1, 1, 2];
mmm[tt_] := 
mm[t] /. {p -> 900, hc -> -17000*1000, ld -> -400*1000, 
mo -> 60*0.453592, cb -> 0.49*1000, mb -> 2000*0.453592, 
td -> 553, to -> 490, h -> 70, t -> tt}
mmm[20]
Plot[mmm[x], {x, 0, 7500}]
```

Im wondering if this solution is an analytical solution and if so how can I extract a simplified form (for perhaps a specific range or only non-imaginary range) or something more presentable. OR is this using numerical techniques to solve it and if so which method is being used.

here is the output solution

```
{{m[t] -> 
   InverseFunction[((-1)^(2/3) (2 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[(-1 + (2 (-1)^(1/3) hc^(1/3) #1^(
         1/3))/(hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(1/3))/Sqrt[3]] + 
     2 Log[(hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(1/3) + (-1)^(1/3) hc^(1/3) #1^(1/3)] - 
     Log[(hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(
       2/3) - (-1)^(1/3) hc^(1/3) (hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(
        1/3) #1^(1/3) + (-1)^(2/3) hc^(2/3) #1^(2/3)]))/(
  2 hc^(1/3) (hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(2/3)) &][(h t)/(cb ld mb p^(2/3)) + ((-1)^(
  2/3) (2 Sqrt[3]ArcTan[(-1 + (
       2 (-1)^(1/3) hc^(1/3) mo^(1/3))/(hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(1/3))/Sqrt[3]] + 
    2 Log[(-1)^(1/3) hc^(1/3) mo^(1/3) + (hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(1/3)] - 
    Log[(-1)^(2/3) hc^(2/3) mo^(2/3) - (-1)^(1/3) hc^(1/3) mo^(
       1/3) (hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(1/3) + (hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(2/3)]))/(
     2 hc^(1/3) (hc mo - cb mb td + cb mb to)^(2/3))]}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

This is a symbolic solution obtained by separating variables and integrating, like this:

```
Integrate[
 1/(-((m[t]^(2/3))/(p^(2/3)))*
      (h/ld (to - td + ((mo - m[t])*hc)/(mb*cb))) /. m[t] -> m), m]
(*
((-1)^(2/3) cb ld mb p^(
   2/3) (2 Sqrt[3]
       ArcTan[(-1 + (
        2 (-1)^(1/3) hc^(1/3) m^(1/3))/(hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(
        1/3))/Sqrt[3]] + 
     2 Log[(-1)^(1/3) hc^(1/3) m^(1/3) + (hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(
        1/3)] - Log[(-1)^(2/3) hc^(2/3) m^(2/3) - (-1)^(1/3) hc^(1/3)
         m^(1/3) (hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(
        1/3) + (hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(2/3)]))/(2 h hc^(
   1/3) (hc mo + cb mb (-td + to))^(2/3))
*)
```

(Evaluate this antiderivative at `m -> mo` and `m -> m[t]`, subtract and set equal to `t`, try solve for `m[t]`.  It looks like inverse functions had to be used.  I had no success simplifying this further.)

Comment: Hi Mike that is helpful, I was confused as to how to interpret the &, #1 symbols and thought something numerical might be happening.. If I wanted to plot this in matlab how could I interpret those symbols?

Comment: The `#1` (or simply `#`) and `&` are part of the "pure function" notation.  See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616) for links to the documentation.  The `&` binds `#1` to the first argument of a function.  For instance `g = f[#1] &` is roughly equivalent to `g[x_] := f[x]`.  I don't know Matlab.  The equations `x == InverseFunction[f[#] &][y]` and `y == f[x]` are equivalent, assuming `f` is 1-1 of course. HTH